# jQuery plugin Roundabout not scaling text in Opera

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, opera

I've extensively tested the jQuery plugin [Roundabout](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/) and got it working nicely in Internet Explorer 6 through 8, Chrome and Firefox.

We would like to support Opera as well. However it does not scale text in moveable items moving to the back.

I'd rather not post a link to my site yet. But the 'official' example has the same bug. The smilies stay same size regardless of distance to front:

http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/demo/toggles/

How can it be made to work in Opera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it scales, but restricts minimum font size. If you change "minimum font size" setting in preferences to 1, then it looks fine.

*It's not a bug, it's a feature :)*